# What is this empty non-numbered row in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

What is this empty non-numbered row in IntelliJ? How can it disable me? Class should be on line 3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable "Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints | Code Vision"

We are working on the fix already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290051/Code-Vision:-inlay-consumes-vertical-space-in-the-editor-even-wh